# Pagination with Django and extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, extjs, pagination

Extjs has gridpanel with pagination capability. However, I think the pagination works only after receiving all the data from the server. (correct me if i'm wrong here). In my case the total data from the server amounts to 20MB in size which I dont want to load through an ajax call (browser gets struck to load this much data). here is what I need. , ,

1. Fetch 1 MB data (approximately) at the page load
2. Use extjs pagination within this data
3. After clicking next button of the paging toolbar, make an ajax call to get the next 1MB data and display that to grid
4. Again use extjs pagination within this data
5. And so on .....

Please suggest how I can achieve this  or are there any existing ways in EXTJS to do this. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

PS: Django is my backend server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I think the pagination works only after receiving all the data from the server.

What makes you think that?

ExtJS Grid Pagination works by definining a page size (let's say 100), and the store then tells the server that it wants the first 100 entries. If you click "next page", the second 100 entries are fetched from the server, and so on.

For the pagination to work as expected, the server API has to understand [`startParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-startParam), [`pageParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-pageParam) and [`limitParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-limitParam).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for clearing that doubt. I will work with this approach. And one follow-up question. At any point of time If I filter my grid store it will apply the filter only on the current 100 entries , correct?

Comment: You can have a ["remote filter"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-remoteFilter) which makes the store call the server whenever the filter changes, to collect the first 100 entries that are subject to the filter, or you can have a local filter, which only filters down the 100 records you have client-side. The remote Filter, once again, requires your server API to support the corresponding parameter, this time, it's called [`filterParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-filterParam).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late but here's a solution for anyone out there that wants to achieve pagination with django & extjs using the "start" & "limit" pagination params sent by EXTJS.

```
def fetchRecords(self, params):
    
    totalCount = 0
    pageNumber = 1
    records = []
    ids = []
    
    #Instanciate your query object
    query = Q()

    #Not really relevant for this case but in case you have any filter criteria params then put them here
    if(params.get("searchStartDate")):
         startDate = datetime.strptime(params.get("searchStartDate"), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
         query &= Q(date_created__gte=startDate)     
    if(params.get("searchEndDate")):
         endDate = datetime.strptime(params.get("searchEndDate"), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
         query &= Q(date_created__lte=endDate)     
    
    # Get the total count, EXT JS Grids need the total count value to be able to paginate
    totalCount = YourModel.objects.filter(query).count()

    #Get the primary keys, we do this because we don't want to get all the objects onto memory. The paginator doesn't 
    #Optimize the fetched data. If your table has millions of records and you load all the record objects to mem, the
    #execution might be quite slow
    your_model_ids_list = YourModel.objects.filter(query).order_by("-id").only('id')

    #Compute the page number based on the pagination "start" & "limit" params sent by EXT grid
    if(int(params.get("start")) != 0 ):
        pageNumber = (int(params.get("start")) / int(params.get("limit"))) + 1

    #Instanciate the paginator object with the primary keys list matching your filter criteria & limit        
    paginator = Paginator(your_model_ids_list, int(params.get("limit")))

    #Get the records that fall on the particular page number that we computed above
    recordIds = paginator.page(pageNumber)

    #Iterate through the record IDs and place them in an array list
    for recordId in recordIds.object_list:
        ids.append(recordId.id)


    #Now fetch the records from your model based on the unique ids that fall on the particular page fetched
    #above
    result = YourModel.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=ids)).order_by("-id")


    #Formulate your response object and return the data
    return {'totalCount': totalCount, 'records': result}
```